# How to set time constraints on a loop in Comman Prompt?

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I am using command prompt to extract information from an API and have an issue. My command prompt code is very fast:
`FOR /L %i IN (0,100,3643453) DO echo curl -glob "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:[20040101+TO+20150101]&limit=100&skip=%i"`
 but now I face the problem of limitations on the number of extractions per minute. I believe that you can only take 100 sets per minute from the API, so is there a way to code a limit in the loop to only run 100 times per minute in the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The GNU sleep command should be what you're looking for.

Completely untested, but it should be something like this:

```
FOR /L %i IN (0,100,3643453) DO echo curl -glob "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:[20040101+TO+20150101]&limit=100&skip=%i; sleep .6s"
```

If you're looking for a MS way of doing this, you might research "Windows 2003 Resource kit tools"

Comment: I didn't want to actually make those api requests, but I did the following as a test and it did as expected: `echo "hi"; sleep .6s; echo "world"`

Comment: I can't run Unix right now (need admin permissions to download a terminal emulator) but this does seem like it would work just as long as it doesn't spit out the sleep command after the url! Thanks!

Comment: I'm on a simple Windows, but am going to download Cygwin once I have permission. I suppose I will end up changing the code a bit, but while I had some time I figured I would look into slowing it down.

Comment: sorry, I didn't recognize the syntax. If you're looking for a MS way of doing this, you might research "Windows 2003 Resource kit tools" If you'll un-accept my answer, maybe someone with more windows experience will give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a native batch version, you can give this a try

@echo off

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "counter=0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do set "minute=%%a"

FOR /L %%i IN (0,100,3643453) DO (
    echo curl -glob "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:[20040101+TO+20150101]&limit=100&skip=%%i"
    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=:" %%a in ("!time!") do if %%a equ !minute! (
        set /a "counter+=1"
        if !counter! geq 100 (
                echo Limit reached, waiting ...
                set /a "wait=60-%%b+2"
                ping -n !wait! localhost >nul 2>nul 
                set "counter=0"
                for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ("!time!") do set "minute=%%c"
        )
    ) else ( set "counter=1" & set "minute=%%a" )
)

endlocal
```